# Troubles with spaces in file paths powershell via .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell

```
set  x=%CD%

runas /netonly /user:server_name\test "powershell.exe -NoExit %x%\deploy.ps1 server_name\MSSQL2012 %x%\_RetainALL.xmla
```

Problem: i need to run PS script as user from server and give arguments in this script. Just simple clicking on one file(.bat actually) for easy deployment ssas solution in server by another IT team.

For this i use runAs command from .bat file. Here some complication: i can't use quotes for evade problem with spaces in file paths in powershell becose i use .bat for runAs(first double quotes will be interpreted as end of runAs.

Also  i thought about using Credential instead runAs, but it also have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
runas /netonly /user:server_name\test "cmd /c powershell.exe -NoExit \"%cd%\deploy.ps1\" server_name\MSSQL2012 \"%cd%\_RetainALL.xmla\" "
```

Escape the quotes in the runas command and run it inside a cmd instance.

Comment: @user3627830, the question talks about quotes being not correctly interpreted by runas, not powershell. What and where is the error?

Comment: fair enought, but powershell understand this: \"%cd%\deploy.ps1\" like %cd%\deploy.ps1\, if i do \'%cd%\deploy.ps1\' then powershell like: \D:\Folder\deploy.ps1.

Comment: @user3627830, code updated. Try this way. I coded a tool to dump command line used to execute and it does not see the backslash when called this way.

Comment: Same mistake, poweshell interprets this comand like: D:\Folder but actual path: D:\Folder 12\deploy.ps1